# Delegates to Pass Data Between Windows C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, delegates

I am attempting to use `Delegates` to pass data between two `Windows`. I want a list of `People` to appear when the user clicks a button on the main `Window`, this will then allow the user to select a `Person`. After doing this it will fill in a `TextBox` on the original form with the `Person` name.

I started off much simpler than this however to get my head around `Delegates` and I'm having issues understanding how to call methods on separate `Windows` with the `Delegates`. This is what I have attempted so far;

The method on the main `Window` that waits for a `string` (ShowMessage);

```
public static DelegateTestWindow.TestDelegate ShowDelegateMessage(string message)
{
    MessageBox.Show(message);
    return null;
}
```

The second `Window` that contains the `Delegate`;

```
public partial class DelegateTestWindow : Window
{
    public delegate string TestDelegate();
    public DelegateTestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TestDelegateClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tDelegate = new TestDelegate(CompanyManagement.ShowDelegateMessage("Test"));
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

This does show a message saying "Test" however it also throws an `Exception` after doing so: `Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.`

The method on the `MainWindow` especially does not look correct to me, however after trying different options this is the closest I've got to a working `Delegate`. Could someone explain where I have (clearly) gone wrong here and how I can improve the system I've got now?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx

Comment: @Mat Can you provide an example of how to use them to pass data between windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Mat linked, events are a special kind of delegate, which is probably what you are looking for.

I've written a small example, hopefully this is enough for you to resolve your issue.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler PersonSelected;
    public String PersonName { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PersonName = "Person's name";
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.Show();
        PersonSelected(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(Form1 form)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form.PersonSelected += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Form1 form1 = sender as Form1;
            if(form1 != null)
                textBox1.Text = form1.PersonName;
        };
    }
}
```

Now, this can be done differently, and better than this, however I think this should suffice. When you get this to work, I recommend you look into another way of doing this. Typically you will create a PersonEventArgs class which inherits from EventArgs. This class then holds a reference to the person. Here is a decent link with an example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Good luck :)